# Factoring limits in polynomials. Leading coefficient not 1.

Tags: calculus, polynomials, self-learning, factoring

I am trying to factor limits in this [Mooculus course](https://mooculus.osu.edu/exercises/limitCompute).

This is the question:

[image]

And they have factored it this way:

[image]

What is the logic behind factoring it this way? It is not the way where you take two integers with a product of a*c and a sum of b. Nor is it factoring out the initial 2. How would I know that I would use `(x+7)`?

The answer by the way is:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $\dfrac{2x^2+2x-84}{-2x^2+4x+126}=\dfrac{x^2+x-42}{-x^2+2x+63}$

Comment: Hi, yes, but when I factor out the 2 like you have done, it is not the correct answer (which is -13/16).

Comment: $=-\dfrac{(x+7)(x-6)}{(x+7)(x-9)}=-\dfrac{x-6}{x-9}$, and as $x\to-7$ this approaches $-\dfrac{-7-6}{-7-9}=-\dfrac{-13}{-16}=-\dfrac{13}{16}$

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're misunderstanding, I think the factoring was just done in a slighty unusual way. Think of it like this:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2x^2+2x-84}{-2x^2+4x+126}&=\frac{2(x^2+x-42)}{-2(x^2-2x-63)}\\[1ex]
&=\frac{2(x-6)(x+7)}{-2(x-9)(x+7)}\\[1ex]
&=\frac{(2x-12)(x+7)}{(-2x+18)(x+7)}
\end{align}
$$

As to why it was written the way it was, it probably was because the only important point was that the two expressions had a common factor of $\,(x+7)\,$.

You also asked how you would know $\,(x+7)\,$ would be a factor of both expressions; that's because otherwise we would not have an indeterminate limit as $\,x \to -7.\,$

Comment: I think that makes sense. They just haven't shown all the steps. So factor out the 2, factor again. Distribute the 2 then done. Thanks.

Comment: I've just reread that last sentence again too. That is it.

Answer (score 1):

After cancelling the common factor $$x+7$$ you can compute the limit
$$\lim_{x\to -7}\frac{(2x-12)(x+7)}{-2x+18)(x+7)}=\lim_{x\to -7}\frac{2x-12}{-2x+18}=\frac{2\times (-7)+12}{-2\times (-7)+18}$$

Comment: Yes, but how do I work out that `x-7` is the common factor from the initial equation? Why do you choose `x-7` over something else? What is the rule here?